# React redux - how to handle events?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, events, redux, middleware

I am learning the concepts of Redux.
From what I understand, reducers are not supposed to mutate state, they return a new state with mutations applied. They are also not supposed to (or maybe even can't?) dispatch other actions.

Given those limitations, that pretty much leaves you with the action creators, middleware, or your React components (if using Redux with React) to call your business logic. So, what I'm trying to do is use Firebase, the wall I've hit, and the questions I have are the following:

- Where should you be creating an instance (i.e. initialising Firebase)?
  Similarly, where should be uninitialising Firebase? Usually I would expect these to be in a service of some kind that you'd call, but I'm not really sure where you would make the call to that service.
- Where should you listen for changes? Firebase provides **.on** on references to allow you to react to changes (i.e. child_added, child_removed) - where should these .on handlers go? I was thinking that surely when one of these events comes in, an action needs to be dispatched with the child in question to update the state, but I can't do this in the reducers, I don't want to do this on a component, and the action creator just seems like an odd place for it to (and when I think about it, how would that even work?)!

### Solution

Finally I ended up following the @ampersand suggestion. I made a module with all the listeners of Firebase application. I import in the Firebase module a `dispatcher.js` file, that is composed by dispatcher function like these:

```
import store from '../store';
import * as actions from './index';

export function addUserMessage(text) {
    store.dispatch(actions.addUserMessage(text));
}

export function addResponseMessage(messageObj) {
    store.dispatch(actions.addResponseMessage(messageObj));
}
```

What I was not understanding was how to dispatch action from an external module. Now I have the concepts clear.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Firebase, but I think middleware is most likely the answer here.

You can write a simple middleware that has access to your Firebase instance and will dispatch these message to the Redux store.

```
// firebase-middleware.js
export default function createFireBaseMiddleware (firebaseInstance) {
  return store => dispatch => {
    fireBaseinstance.on(message => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'FIREBASE_MESSAGE',
        payload: message,
      })
    })

    return action => {
      if (action.type === 'TALK_BACK_TO_FIREBASE' {
        firebaseInstance.postMessage(action)
      }

      // Let the action continue down the path of middleware to the store
      return dispatch(action)
    }
  }
}

// createStore.js
export default createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(createFireBaseMiddleware(myfirebaseInstance)
)
```

Comment: I like your solution. I'll try to code it and I'll let you know

Answer (score 1):

To tack onto @chautelly's response, generally services in react/redux are just modules—create your firebase instance inside a standalone module, export the appropriate object from it, and import where needed.

**database.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'api key',
  authDomain: 'db_name.firebaseio.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://db_name.firebaseio.com/'
});

const database = firebase.database();

export default database;
```

Comment: In your case where would you put the .on() listeners? In the action creators?

Comment: Yes, I'd probably start there. Action creators would set up handling for .on() and dispatch the appropriate action with the returned/resulting data.

Comment: Isn't a bad pattern to let  a reducer triggering action?

Comment: Yes, it is—your reducers should be pure. All they should care about are slices of state. You'd be using action creators instead of reducers. Your question was [posted on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/3tkega/redux_how_do_you_handle_events/) about a year ago if you want to dig through the conversation over there. Might lead to some more insight.

Comment: I already read it, but I am not able to find a working solution.

Comment: @chautelly's middleware example is firing a generic action using an event listener from an initialized firebase client/object. Have you tried that out? Do you have a repo up that we can check out?